# Running Telegram bot made on python as background service on Ubuntu

Tags: python, telegram, systemctl, telebot

Couldn't run telegram bot as background service. When run directly from terminal  - it works fine.

I've made a simple telegram bot using telebot library:

```
import telebot

TOKEN = 'my-token'
bot = telebot.TeleBot(TOKEN)

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def proc_msg(message):
    chat_id = message.chat.id
    bot.send_message(chat_id,text="I'm test bot. Sorry, can't answer anything else. Made for dummy tests.")

bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0)
```

It works when I just run the script via terminal:

```
python test_bot.py
```

I need to run the bot as background service with automatic restart after reboots, so I made **test_bot.service** file:

```
[Unit]
Description=Test Bot
After=multi-user.target

[Service]
Type=simple
Restart=always
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python /etc/tg_bots/test4477qwe_bot/test_bot.py

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Then put the file to `/etc/systemd/system` and run `systemctl daemon-reload`. At this stage everything is fine, my service is in list given by `systemctl`

But when I'm trying run the service using command `systemctl start test_bot` - nothing happens. It actually looks like `systemctl start test_bot` is hanging.

What could be wrong?
(System is Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS. Maybe it is not the best choice for running python-telegram-bots?)

Comment: Check journalctl for logging

Comment: You left your **Private Bot Token** in your code. You should revoke it **ASAP** by talking to the [@BotFather](https://t.me/BotFather). People might abuse the token.

Comment: journalctl output is just "-- No entries --"

Thanks for fixing API-key. Actually this bot was made just for test, an is gonna be deleted as soon as solution be found

Comment: What does `systemctl status test_bot.service` show?

Answer (score 0):

You can just start script with this code and it will work in background.

```
nohup python test_bot.py &
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Running in background is a kind of half-solution because it requires manual script restart after server reboot or script crash. So making background service is prefrrable

Answer (score 0):

After numerous attempts I just changed operation system to CentOS 9. Now script successfully works as background service. Probably something wrong with exact Ubuntu version provided by my VPS hoster